# Assistance creating simple nav-bar.

Tags: html, alignment

Could someone help me. I am a beginner and I am just trying to understand how code works. I know this seems stupid but I couldn't find anyone asking this question. I found that my Navigation bar is going across my screen and that their is no margin. I tried it with it but I don't know where to add the "align" but it doesn't work. If you do answer this question color or cool effects to make this nav bar actually look good. Thank you for the help and I appreciate anyone that tries.I don't know how to add code here so please read the comments.

Comment: <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LYJ</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn">SURVEY</button>
  </div>
</nav>

Answer (score 0):

ok here is a simple nav bar you make,
first you should learn about display:flex
Display flex is used to align divs or elements inside a parent
for example consider this example

```
<style>
.parent{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
width:50%;
justify-contents:space-between;
}
</style>
<div class="parent">
<div class="child_one">
<p>menu</p>
</div>
<div class="child_two">
<p>menu</p>
</div>
<div class="child_three">
 <p>menu</p>
</div>
</div>
```

if you run the above code you will see a output where all the menuitems will be aligned inline,so you have a basic navbar structure .But to make it responsive you should learn media queries( to make the display flex to block)

Comment: Im sorry when I tried the code you gave me didn't do anything. I believe its the "justify-contents part but Im no expert.